# Permissions Error - Trying to get friends using android facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add a feature to my android app that allows users to "checkin" with other people tagged to the checkin.
I have the checkins method working no problem and can tag some one by adding the user ID as a parameter (see code below)

```
public void postLocationTagged(String msg, String tags, String placeID, Double lat, Double lon) {
    Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API location post");
    String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
     try {
         if (isSession()) {
            String response = mFacebook.request("me");
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("access_token", access_token);
            parameters.putString("place", placeID);
            parameters.putString("Message",msg);
            JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
            coordinates.put("latitude", lat);
            coordinates.put("longitude", lon);
            parameters.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());
            parameters.putString("tags", tags);
            response = mFacebook.request("me/checkins", parameters, "POST");
            Toast display = Toast.makeText(this, "Checkin has been posted to Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            display.show();
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
               Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }
        } else {
         // no logged in, so relogin
         Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
         mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

This works fine (I've posted it in case it is of help to anyone else!), the problem i am having is i am trying to create a list of the users friends so they can select the friends they want to tag. I have the method getFriends (see below) which i am then going to use to generate an AlertDialog that the user can select from which in turn will give me the id to use in the above "postLocationTagged" method.

```
public void getFriends(CharSequence[] charFriendsNames,CharSequence[] charFriendsID, ProgressBar progbar) {
    pb = progbar;
    try {
        if (isSession()) {
            String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
            friends = charFriendsNames;
            friendsID = charFriendsID;
           Log.d(TAG, "Getting Friends!");
           String response = mFacebook.request("me");
           Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
           parameters.putString("access_token", access_token);
           response = mFacebook.request("me/friends", parameters, "POST");

           Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
           if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                   response.equals("false")) {
              Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
           }

        } else {
        // no logged in, so relogin
        Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
        mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i look at the response in the log it reads:

"got responce: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException", "message":"(#200) Permissions error"}}"

I have looked through the graphAPI documentation and searched for similar questions but to no avail! I'm not sure if i need to request extra permissions for the app or if this is something your just not allowed to do! Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to implement a RequestListener when making the request to the Facebook graph API. I have the new getFriends() method (see below) which uses the AsyncGacebookRunner to request the data.

```
public void getFriends(CharSequence[] charFriendsNames,String[] sFriendsID, ProgressBar progbar) {
    try{
        //Pass arrays to store data
        friends = charFriendsNames;
        friendsID = sFriendsID;
        pb = progbar;
        Log.d(TAG, "Getting Friends!");
        //Create Request with Friends Request Listener
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The AsyncFacebookRunner makes the the request using the custom FriendsRequestListener (see below) which implements the RequestListener class;

```
private class FriendsRequestListener implements RequestListener {
    String friendData;

    //Method runs when request is complete
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FriendListRequestONComplete");
        //Create a copy of the response so i can be read in the run() method.
        friendData = response; 

        //Create method to run on UI thread
        FBConnectActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Parse JSON Data
                    JSONObject json;
                    json = Util.parseJson(friendData);

                    //Get the JSONArry from our response JSONObject
                    JSONArray friendArray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                    //Loop through our JSONArray
                    int friendCount = 0;
                    String fId, fNm;
                    JSONObject friend;
                    for (int i = 0;i<friendArray.length();i++){
                        //Get a JSONObject from the JSONArray
                        friend = friendArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //Extract the strings from the JSONObject
                        fId = friend.getString("id");
                        fNm = friend.getString("name");
                        //Set the values to our arrays
                        friendsID[friendCount] = fId;
                        friends[friendCount] = fNm;
                        friendCount ++;
                        Log.d("TEST", "Friend Added: " + fNm);
                    }

                    //Remove Progress Bar
                    pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Feel free to use any of this code in your own projects, or ask any questions about it.

Comment: This looks like ovekill. (Having just debugged as similar issue), it looks more like you were doing a POST request when you should have been doing a GET.

Comment: is it possible to use a search text box to filter friends by name ??

Answer (score 2):

You might need the following permissions:

- user_checkins
- friends_checkins
- read_friendlists
- manage_friendlists
- publish_checkins

Check the related ones from the API docs. Before that, make sure that which line causes this permission error and try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet, I've just figured it out, it wasn't the permissions but the way i was submitting the request to the graph API. I'm going to have some dinner then comment and post my solution. Thank you for your answer anyway - looking through the permissions for read/manage friendslist gave me an awesome idea to implement in my app!

Answer (score 0):

You can     `private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream","status_update",xxxx};`xxx is premissions