# Get Facebook friend list - Android

Tags: android

I am new in Facebook integration with android. I've logged in to Facebook by using facebook-android-SDK. Now I want to get all friends details and display in ListView. How can I do this?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6236251/940096)

Comment: This may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316740/permissions-error-trying-to-get-friends-using-android-facebook-sdk

Comment: I am not able to extend BaseRequestListener class....:(

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/BaseRequestListener.java)

Comment: Hey Spk, thanks a lot. This helped me a lot. Now I'll post another question related to this.... :P  and please provide this link as an answer so that it may helpful to others. Enjoy

Answer (score 6):

Go with following code to get frends list :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "name, picture");
        JSONObject jsonFrends = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/friends", params));
```

Comment: plz give complete detail how we get Facebook friends

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend following the tutorial on [Fetching User Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/) and then instead of executing

```
    ...
if (state.isOpened()) {
    userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Request user data and show the results
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null) {
                // Display the parsed user info
                userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
            }
        }
    });
}
...
```

use [Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#executeMyFriendsRequestAsync%28Session,%20GraphUserListCallback%29) which is part of the Request class.

EDIT: Which also has the advantage of using the Facebook Android SDK to parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this way :

```
Using the graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="your access_token"
```